# Хочу создать через скрипт T-SQL базу данных,но выходит эта ошибка

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
USE master
CREATE DATABASE Cim
--Создание отношения
CREATE TABLE факультеты (

idФакультет int NOT NULL,

Факультет varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (idФакультет));
```

Comment: Ну там написано, что и БД с таким названием и таблица с таким названием в этой базе уже существуют. Либо выберите другие названия, либо предварительно удалите эти объекты.

Comment: Я удалял ,но почему-то вылазит все равно эта ошибка,даже если изменить название

Comment: Попробуйте как-то по частям делать - сначала отдельно создать базу. Потом отдельно создать таблицу. Чтобы понять, на чём всё-таки затык.

Comment: И скорее всего после создания базы вам надо `USE Cim` будет сделать, чтобы дальше с этой базой работать.

Comment: Отдельно создается эта таблица факультеты ,а если как на скриншоте ,то постоянно эта ошибка

Comment: USE master
CREATE DATABASE Cim
--Создание отношения
USE Cim
CREATE TABLE факультет (

idФакультет int NOT NULL,

Факультет varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (idФакультет))  во так?

Comment: `use master` можете вообще убрать